# Getting error USE statement is not supported to switch between databases with Azure Synapse formerly SQLDW

Tags: azure-sql-data-warehouse, azure-synapse-analytics

Whenever I attempt to submit a query to Azure Synapse SQLDB (or try to do anything with the database from my application called DBForge) I get the following error message:

USE statement is not supported to switch between databases

Can someone let me know how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?toc=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=azure-sqldw-latest) for the `USE` statement, you'll see that it is not supported for Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly Azure SQL DW).

To change database contexts, you'll have to open an explicit connection to the desired database.

If you're having issues with your IDE, try [specifying the desired database in your connection string](https://docs.devart.com/studio-for-sql-server/connecting-to-databases/managing-db-connections.html) when you connect so there is no switching required.

Comment: thanks for reaching out. I've taken a brief look at the link you provided and it looks promising. I have also submitted a support ticket to dbForge

Comment: How @LowlyDBA, I tried the suggestion in the link you provided, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @Carltonp edit your question and add what your connection looks like, as well as the command you're trying to execture